# ERROR, Call to a member function send() on null

Tags: laravel, octobercms

The font-end of my october CMS instance suddenly started giving me out the following error code:

`Call to a member function send() on null`

```
$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Any Idea what could be causing it? I probably was adding a translation for another language while this happened.

I tried to find other posts about similar problems, but there seem to be so many cause for this error and I'm not a programmer. Thank you!

[screenshot of error code, visiting the front-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKEeS.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probable reason is that you're using a custom `middleware` that has a case where it doesn't return `$next($request)` or anything, which will return `null` instead of a response.

Comment: Thank you for your response! So you are suggesting to disable one plugin after the other an check if that fixes it?

Comment: @andue from another user experience **"I did checked all of my plugins and this plugin name Redirect is the issue."**

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I managed to remove the error by dumping the home-page and creating another one from scratch. But I also disabled this plugin that plugin. Thank you for your help!